# About Alamofire version for use manager

Tags: swift, alamofire

I use this code.

```
var apiPath : String = "/api/list/"
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60
let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["_token" : self._token]
manager.request(.GET, self._host + self._url + apiPath, parameters: nil)
    .responseSwiftyJSON ({ (request, response, resultJson, error) in
        if (resultJson["Success"]) {
             //get list success
        } else {
            println("request : \(request)")
            println("response : \(response)")
            println("resultJson : \(resultJson)")
            println("error : \(error)")
        }

})
```

And I got some problem

Alamofire version 1.2.1 : No Problem

Alamofire version 1.2.2 & 1.2.3 :

```
request : { URL: https://test.com/api/list/ }

response : nil

resultJson : null
```

> error : Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
>   UserInfo=0x7feb92c434f0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https
>   ://test.com/api/list/, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http s://test.com/api/list/})

why response was nil and resultJson was null on version 1.2.2 and 1.2.3
Please help me what problem in this code..

Comment: And there is no problem with `Alamofire.request(...`,why?

Comment: because i want setting to time out of request like this , 'configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60'

Comment: yes,i want setting the header field,so same problem.

Comment: The request is being cancelled because of a failed authentication challenge.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just encountered the same problem as you today after updating Alamofire from 1.2.1 to 1.2.3.

I discovered by adding "manager.session.invalidateAndCancel()" at the end and inside the responseJSON block fixed this issue. But what I cannot get my head around is that how can this line of code INSIDE the responseJSON block affects the responseJSON results.

Anyway I will just run with this fix until the Alamofire team fixes it or someone explains to me why this is happening.

Comment: could you have a look at my code? I still can't fix it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289074/authenticated-http-request-swift-alamofire?noredirect=1

Comment: This is because this line with make sure the manager is retained until the inner block has been executed. Basically you created a retain cycle to 'fix' the problem. The real problem is that the manager is being released before it reached the response block with that line. You need to make sure you keep a reference to the manager.

Comment: @KevinR - how should you make sure you keep a reference to the manager?

Comment: @raklos you can either use the default manager (or sharedManager if using 4.0 or later), or, if you define your own configuration, make sure to keep a static reference somewhere. This way the instance is globally accessible and won't create a possible retain cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your API endpoint indicates to a secure connection:

> http**S**://test.com/api/list/

Just try it just in case, maybe it repeats your situation.

In my case, **this was a typo** in the API manager code. Which from the part can be said is connected with App Transport Security Settings.

Just changed the protected protocol from `httpS://` to `http://` and the error:

> NSURLErrorDomain Code = -999 "cancelled"

was gone and **it all worked**!

+And also if you had a similar problem. Be sure to **discuss this with a backend specialist** who deals with the server or API configuration for your application. This means that the server does not have valid security certificates. Perhaps you still need a secure connection. Or this specialist can again configure everything back from `http://` to `httpS://`, and I'm not sure (did not check) whether this will work again when in the code you are already using a non-secure `http://` connection.