# Authenticated http request swift Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift2, xcode7

I'm struggling with getting this to work to make request to my API. Without a token works, but when I try to add additional headers, things turn to be complicated, for me.

First, the structure.
one class called: **APIAsyncTask** that makes the requests

one class called **APIParams**, just a data holder to send parameters to the *APIAsyncTask* class.

one class called **DatabaseAPI** that makes that builds the parameters, and send that to the *APIAsyncTask* class.

**DatabaseAPI**

```
func someMethod()
{
    let task = APIAsyncTasks()
    task.registerCallback { (error, result) -> Void in
        print("Finished task, back at DatabaseAPI")
    }
    let params2 = APIParams(request: .GET, apiPath: "Posts/1", apiToken: "4iTX-56w")
    task.APIrequest(params2)
}
```

**APIAsyncTask**

This part is for fixing another error, because manager was not global, the task got cancelled quickly.

```
var manager : Manager!

init(authenticatedRequest : Bool, token: String?)
{
    manager = Alamofire.Manager()
    print("Pre \(manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders?.count)")
    if(authenticatedRequest && token != nil)
    {
        var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders!   
        defaultHeaders["Authorization"] = "bearer \(token)"
        let configuration = Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration
        configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders

        manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
    }
    print("Post \(manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders?.count)")
}
```

After some decision making, it comes down to this part.

```
 private func GetRequest(url: String!,token : String?, completionHandler: (JSON?, NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSError?) -> () ) -> ()
{
    print("Begin Get Request")

    if(token != nil)//if token is not nil, make authenticated request
    {
        print("just before request: \(manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders?.count)")
        manager.request(.GET, url, parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
            print("Get Request (authenticated), inside alamofire request")
            var resultJson : JSON?
            if(json != nil)
            {
                resultJson = JSON(json!)
            }
            completionHandler(resultJson, request, response, error)
        }
    }
    else
    {
     //working part without token
```

So as the code is now, I get an error on completing:

[image: runtime error]

Mattt himself [gives the answer](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/111) of using `Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders`
, so that should be fine...

I suspect it has something to do with the multiple threads, according to [this](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/) blog. Or, since it is something about CFNetwork, it could be because my API does not use SSL? I disabled NSAppTransportSecurity

I'm kind of new to swift, so examples would be really appreciated! Thankyou!

Comment: Should you keep strong reference to manager. I am not sure but could you check that,.

Comment: Suggested actions? I'm not sure how I would make it a weak reference..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the majority of your code looks solid.

The error leads me to believe that CFNetwork is having difficulty figuring out how to compute the protection space for the challenge. I would also assume you are getting a basic auth challenge since you are attaching an `Authorization` header.

Digging through your logic a bit more with this in mind led me to see that your not attaching your `token` to the string properly inside the `Authorization` header. You need to do the following instead.

```
defaultHeaders["Authorization"] = "bearer \(token!)"
```

Otherwise your `Authorization` header value is going to include `Optional(value)` instead of just `value`.

That's the only issue I can see at the moment. If you could give that a try and comment back that would be great. I'll update my answer accordingly if that doesn't actually solve your problem.

Best of luck!

Comment: hi cnoon, thanks for taking the time to try and figure out what is wrong. Also, thanks for telling me that my code looks pretty solid. I indeed get an auth challange. In the meantime I've spent time on logging in, thus getting a real access token. So I just tried it, with your answer, with a real valid access token, and it works! That.. little ! did the trick.. HOWEVER: I was checking if it was just luck because it now is a valid access token, turns out, that if it's invalid or expired, it still throws the same error :(

Comment: so, long story short, the `!` is required, but instead of 401 http code when invalid or expired access token, I get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your headers in your request with `Alamofire 2` and `Swift 2`.

For an example: [go to example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647941/alamofire-2-0-and-swift-2-header-is-not-working-see-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: did you test if it throws exception when token is invalid? Or does it return 401?

Comment: I handled the error on server side. My header "Authorization" was coming null. Now it is working.

Comment: I mean: When the token, you are setting in the header, is invalid or expired, will it crash / throw exception or will it return 401?

Comment: No, nothing happened that's why I struggled to find what's going on.