# Alamofire 2.0 and Swift 2 - Header is not working. See how to fix it

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire

When I upgraded my project to `swift 2` with `Alamofire 2` `headers` stopped working without any errors in code. The reason is that `headers` are not working old style.

```
 // login with Alamofire 1 and Swift 1.2 - WITH HEADER
 func loginAlamofire_1(username:String) {
            manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "yourToken"]
            manager.request(.POST, "login_url", parameters: ["username" : username], encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON)
                .response{ (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
                    if error != nil{
                        print("error!")
                    } else {
                        print("welcome")
                    }
            }
        }
```

You can see the fixed version below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the `header problem` by sending `headers` in `requests`.

```
// login with Alamofire 2.0 and Swift 2.0 - WITH HEADER
func loginAlamofire_2(username:String) {
    manager.request(.POST, "login_url", parameters: ["username" : username], encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON, headers: ["Authorization": "yourToken"])
        .response{ (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil{
                print("error!")
            } else {
                print("welcome")
            }
    }
}
```